# Using BubbleSort in C# to sort Integers, But Want to Move Whole Object

Tags: c#, sorting, object, bubble-sort

I have implemented a simple BubbleSort to sort my tasks based on their priority and it looks like this

```
int temp = 0;
for (int write = 0; write < taskStructure.TasksArray.Count; write++)
{
    for (int sort = 0; sort < taskStructure.TasksArray.Count - 1; sort++)
    {
        if (taskStructure.TasksArray[sort].taskPriority > taskStructure.TasksArray[sort + 1].taskPriority)
        {
            temp = taskStructure.TasksArray[sort + 1].taskPriority;
            taskStructure.TasksArray[sort + 1].taskPriority = taskStructure.TasksArray[sort].taskPriority;
            taskStructure.TasksArray[sort].taskPriority = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fantastic, and it sorts them in the correct order, however, it literally swaps the integers around in that column only and not the object (Task) that it is linked to.

For example:

I have two tasks

Name: TestName1 Desc: TestDesc1 Priority: 5
Name: TestName2 Desc: TestDesc2 Priority: 3

After my BubbleSort:

Name: TestName1 Desc: TestDesc1 Priority: **3**
Name: TestName2 Desc: TestDesc2 Priority: **5**

But it needs to do (Move the actual object):

Name: **TestName2** Desc: **TestDesc2** Priority: **3**
Name: **TestName1** Desc: **TestDesc1** Priority: **5**

Hope this makes it clearer, is there any way that I can move the object(task) that the priority is linked to as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to change the swapping procedure (the innermost block of code) like this and remove the `int temp = 0` line at the beginning:

```
var temp = taskStructure.TasksArray[sort + 1];
taskStructure.TasksArray[sort + 1] = taskStructure.TasksArray[sort];
taskStructure.TasksArray[sort] = temp;
```

But note, you can also use the [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
Array.Sort(taskStructure.TasksArray, (x, y) => x.taskPriority - y.taskPriority);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it when I get back and if works, I will mark this as answer! Thank you so much for your help! I know I could use .Sort() but I want to see how it actually operates being the scenes if that makes sense? I would like to learn the different sorting Algorithms 

Comment: @IAmZingy Sure thing. Writing your own implementations of common algorithms is definitely great programming practice. But remember that when you go to start writing *production* code, every line needs to be maintained and is a potential source of bugs. Using built-in functions can save you a lot of time and energy.

Comment: Hi @p.s.w.g I have implemented your solution but I get on your first line. `Cannot implicitly convert type '..........taskStructure' to 'int' and on your third line I get `'Cannot simplicity convert type 'int' to '..........taskStructure'`

I can rectify the first problem by converting it to an integer, but I cannot rectify the third line problem, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @IAmZingy Yeah, I forgot to mention that the temporary variable needs to be typed as task object. See my updated answer.

Comment: That worked thankyou, it now makes sense, I'm just starting out so I'm practicing my code, but your assistance has definitely taught me something and your advice about production code is something I will embed into my programming knowledge fro the rest of my time. Thankyou so much! Answer marked!